# Inherit from Generic Class in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I'm attempting to inherit a class from a generic class in Swift. I'm using Swift v5.9.

Suppose we have the following example code:

```
class A<T>
{}

class B : A
{}
```

Where I want class `B` to inherit from class `A`, which is a generic class with the template type of `T`.

Attempting to compile the above results in:

```
reference to generic type 'A' requires arguments in <...>
class B : A
```

Unfortunately, the [Swift official documentation on Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics/) does not appear to cover such a case, so I was left to guess a potential solution.

Given the wording of the error, I assumed that I would need to specify that the inherited class `A` is a generic of type `T` when declaring class `B` as such:

```
class A<T>
{}

class B : A<T>
{}
```

However, this results in:

```
cannot find type 'T' in scope
class B : A<T>
```

What is the proper way to inherit from a generic class in Swift?

Comment: Is B supposed to be generic to? Otherwise the specialization of A might be `class B : A<Int>` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for asking, `B` is not supposed to be a generic here.

Comment: So problem solved then or…?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think so.. Unfortunately I was looking for a way to not have to declare the inherited class `B` as a generic, because I don't use any generic fields in `B`, however since it inherits from the generic class `A` and I don't know beforehand what the generic type will be, it seems that I'm forced to declare `B` as generic as well... thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said in a reply to a comment:

> B is not supposed to be a generic here

So that means, you must know what `T` is going to. Let's say, `T` will be `MyClass`. Then the definition of `B` becomes:

```swift
class B : A<MyClass>
{}
```

On the other hand, if in fact you don't know what `T` will be, then `B` will have to be a generic too. You can re-use the same `T`:

```swift
class B<T> : A<T>
{}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was originally looking for a way of not forcing `B` to be generic, as `B` isn't supposed to use any generic fields, however since I don't know what the generic type will be beforehand, it appears I unfortunately have to force `B` to be generic because it inherits from generic `A`.